# AS3 quiz and answers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

Here's my problem;

I want to make a quiz that at the end shows a person the qualities he/she has for chosing a specific college course. The quiz will ask 10 questions which each have 2 answers, upon clicking an answer, points will be earned for a specific course.

For example the question could be 'Do you want to work with computers, or with people?'

Upon answering Computers points will be gained at the courses Informatica, Designing and Editing
Upon answering People points will be gained at the courses Doctor, Social Worker etc (Im just naming things here for example)

I want people to go through the quiz, answer the questions, and see in the end how much points they earned for each course, seeing which courses are best suited for their potential.

Now the code could be simple. I have Flash CS5 and use Actionscript 3. On my first frame of Layer one I have the first question and two buttons and have this code:

```
stop();
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release1);
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, release2);
var option1:Number = 0;
var option2:Number = 0;

function release1(){
    option1 += 1;
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

function release2(){
    option2 += 1;
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

and on the second frame I have a normal text saying something like 'the results are:' and then two (for the time being) dynamic text boxes in which I want to have the results.

Here's the problem, I don't know how to show the results. I have this as code:

```
txt1.text = option1;
txt2.text = option2;
```

But I get the error `1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type String.`

...unfortunatly Im kinda new to CS5 and Actionscript 3 so I don't know what to do. When I try my script out it just plays it like a movieclip.

Can someone tell me wheter Im doing a small thing wrong or am I entirely on the wrong course in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as the error description says, you're trying to assign something of type `String` to something of type `Number`.  You've got the right idea of setting the text box to display the scores but `txt1.text` will only accept a `String`.  You can use `toString()` to cast the number so that your text field will accept it:

`txt1.text = option1.toString();`.

Also, to stop the project playing like a movie clip add the command `stop();` on each frame you would like the application to wait at (you've already added it to the first frame so just add it to the second).